# How to do dynamic design in xaml in xamarin forms

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I need to dynamic design in xaml. Is there a method such as asp.net mvc razor or another method?

Comment: The question is Off topic as per StackOverflow but anyway I do not think there is something like that here.

Comment: what do you want to dynamic design?maybe you could do that in code-behind

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I want is expanding the page when items add. It solved my problem.

Xaml;

```
<StackLayout Padding="20">
            <Picker Title="myTitle"
                    SelectedItem="{Binding Selected}"
                    FontSize="15">
                <Picker.Items>
                    <x:String>Item 1</x:String>
                    <x:String>Item 2</x:String>
                </Picker.Items>
            </Picker>

            <Label Text="myLabel"
                   Margin="5,0,0,0"
                   TextColor="Gray"
                   IsVisible="{Binding IsVisible}"
                   FontSize="13"/>
</StackLayout>
```

ViewModel;

```
private string _selected;
public string Selected
{
     get { return _selected; }
     set
     {
         _selected = value;
         if (_selected == "Item 1")
         {
             IsVisible = true;  
         }
         else if (_selected == "Item 2")
         {
             IsVisible = false;
         }
         OnPropertyChanged("Selected");
     }
}
```